# Equivalence Relation? Column-equivalence on the set of all $m\times n$ matrices.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

How do I show that column equivalence on the set of all $m\times n$ matrices is an equivalence relation?

I know that to show it is an equivalence relation, I need to show that column equivalence is transitive, symmetric, and reflexive.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the expression "column *equivalence*" does most of your work for you.

> I know that to show it is an equivalence relation, I need to show that column equivalence is  transitive, symmetric, and reflexive.

Just do exactly that: show that your column equivalence is transitive, symmetric, and reflexive on the set of all $m\times n$ matrices. To do this:

Review your notes and/or text as reference, and answer:

- What must be true for column equivalence to be ***reflexive***? $\\$ For an arbitrary $m\times n$ matrix we'll call $A$, are the columns of $A$ equivalent to the columns of $A$?
- What must be true for column equivalence to be ***symmetric***? $\\$  If matrix $A_{m\times n}$ is column equivalent to matrix $B_{m\times n}$, is $B$ column equivalent to $A$?
- What must be true for column equivalence to be ***transitive***? $\\$ Likewise, does the column equivalence of $A$ with $B$ and the column equivalence of $B$ with $C$ imply that $A$ and $C$ must be column equivalent?

If you can answer "yes" to each of the above, then we've established that column equivalence on $m\times n$ matrices is an equivalence relation.

Unpacking the ***definitions of the properties of an equivalence relation*** is key here, along with the fact that the relation in question is defined as "column ***equivalence***".